# approve multiple records at once

Tags: ruby

how to achieve this Scenario:

admin to select multiple records using a checkbox and click a button to approve selected, which will change the status of the selected items to approved at once. records are like posts.

### here is my code:

config/routes:

```
resources :time_cards do
collection do
  get 'management'
  put 'approve_multiple'
end
member do
  get 'review'
  get 'tracking'
  patch 'approve_or_reject'
end
```

end

---

html:

```
    <%= form_tag({controller: 'time_cards', action: 'approve_multiple'}, method: 'put', id: 'approve_multiple_time_card_form') do %>
      <% @time_cards.each do |time_card| %>
          <tr>
            <% if time_card.status.downcase == 'submitted' %>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "time_cards_to_approve[]", time_card.id %></td>
            <% else %>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <% end %>
            <td><%= time_card.id %></td>
            <td><%= time_card.week_of.to_date.strftime('%B %-d, %Y') %></td>
            <td><%= time_card.user.name %></td>
            <td><%= time_card.status %></td>
            <td><%= output_hours(time_card.time_card_entries) %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to review_time_card_path(time_card) do %>
                  <% if time_card.status.downcase == 'submitted' %>
                      <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                  <% end %>
              <% end %>

            </td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      <%= submit_tag "Approve Selected", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
```

---

controller:

```
#PUT /time_cards/approve_multiple
  def approve_multiple
    authorize TimeCard

    @time_cards.update_all({status: 'Approved'}, {id: params[:time_cards_to_approve]})
    respond_to do |format|
      if !@time_cards.errors
        format.json { render json: { notice: 'Time cards approved successfully.'} }
        format.html { redirect_to redirect_to management_time_cards_path, notice: 'Time cards approved successfully.'}
      else
        format.json { render json: { error: @time_cards.errors, alert: 'There was a problem approving the time card.'}}
        format.html { redirect_to management_time_cards_path, alert: @time_cards.errors}
      end
    end
```

### end

??? I don't no where it is wrong?

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service, what have you tried so far and where have you not succeeded? Post examples of your code, and try searching on SO/Google before posting

Comment: Several steps: 1) build the UI (records with checkboxes, etc.). 2) in the controller (you're using rails, I assume?) handle posted form and find all the matching elements, according to checkboxes. 3) Do a mass-update on those records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send these ids to an action like this

```
Post.where(id: params[:ids]).update_all(approved: true)
```

`params[:ids]` is an array of posts' ids

`update_all` returns the number of the updated records

Ops, I took for granted we were talking about rails but it's never mentioned.

Comment: Haha @Ursus it seems everyone else has taken it for granted too

Comment: I am using ruby on rails.

Comment: my code is similar to what you say... is there a way to post my code here/

Comment: @Ursus <%= check_box_tag "time_cards_to_approve[]", time_card.id %>

Comment: @Ursus yet where I try to update all it cannot find the time_cards_ids

Comment: I think you have some problems with the UI

Comment: @Ursus @time_cards.update_all({status: 'Approved'}, {id: params[:time_cards_to_approve]})

Comment: @Ursus I have updated the question with the code... please help